# JAR to EXE convertor?

Tags: java, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Sorry for a newbie question, just starting with Java under windows... what is the best way to convert an executable jar file into a windows exe file?

If possible, so that the GUI would also become windows-style, as the java's gui seems kinda ugly. :)

Thanks!

Comment: yu will have to use installshield fm nullsoft

Comment: [Here's a reference](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html) that I found with a bit of Googling.  I'm not sure the purpose of it, but hopefully that provides you a hint or two.

Comment: Launch it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  That will work on Windows, *nix & OS X.  Use the native look & feel.  If you really just want an EXE, consider using .Net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net) or [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net).

Both are free and will allow you to create java executable, and will automatically find / download JRE on users' workstations.

Also note, that the *look-and-feel* of your Java application is up to you. You declare the look and feel using

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

and this way you replace default *look-and-feel* (which i think is *Metal*).
Place it somewhere at the very beginning of your `main()` method (or at least before swing initializes).

Also read about [other ways of changing Java look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

Comment: About the look-and-feel: Other option would be to use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) as the GUI framework.

Comment: @buc SWT is a way, but it's not entirely java, requires native libraries, and has quite different philosophy. I don't think, that the decision whether to chose SWT or not should be taken when consdering LAF. There are much more important aspects to consider in such decision, than LAF.